# How can I show a rating bar in an Android listview?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm trying to create a mail program in android. I've created a list from the server, it shows a mail list view (like gmail and others). Now I want to display a rating for important mails. How can I use the rating option in the mail listview? Anyone know the way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Just put a `RatingBar` in your list rows. When the user adjusts the rating, update your data model to reflect the new rating. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/FancyLists/RateList) demonstrating the use of a `RatingBar` in `ListView` rows.